# Limiting exposure of a class via interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to figure out how to limit the exposure of certain functions without having to rewrite it for each requirement.
I've got a service called AccountService in my Infrastructure Project that handles the Identity aspect of the system.
To consume this service I've got two MVC projects, one for the administrator and the other for the Customer.

The administrator need not have a registration function, so how do I limit this functionality?

Here's what I thought of doing.

**Administrator AccountService Interface**

```
namespace Application.Interfaces.Account.Administrator
{
    public  interface IAccountService
    {
        string Login(string username, string password);
    }
}
```

**Customer AccountService Interface**

```
namespace Application.Interfaces.Account.Customer
{
    public  interface IAccountService
    {
        string Register(RegisterDto dto);
        string Login(string username, string password);
    }
}
```

**Administrator AccountService**

```
namespace Application.Identity.Administrator
{
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Application.Interfaces.Account.Administrator;
    using Domain.Entities;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

    public class AccountService : IAccountService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public AccountService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, ILogger<AccountService> logger)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public string Login(string username, string password)
        {
            // login code
        }
    }
}
```

**Customer AccountService**

```
namespace Application.Identity.Customer
{
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Application.Interfaces.Account.Customer;
    using Domain.Entities;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    public class AccountService : IAccountService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public AccountService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, ILogger<AccountService> logger)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public string Login(string username, string password)
        {
            // login code
        }
        public string Register(RegisterDto dto)
        {
            // register code
        }
    }
}
```

How do I avoid code duplication?

Comment: Assuming you can't inject either of the `AccountService` objects directly, is using an interface  not already sufficient?

Comment: Similar to UserManager and SignInManager, you can split your interfaces to two based on reponsibilities rather than topic. IAccountManager for registration and ILoginService for login. Then implement it in same class or different classes. Honestly, you don't have to implement your own interface because identity framework already provides interfaces for the same.

Comment: @John I suppose using an interface should be fine, but it seems like I'm not following the DRY principle, since I have some code duplicated across both the instances of AccountService.

Comment: @MatJ Oh yes, this makes sense. I could split the functionality of login and registration and inherit them to the AccountServices.

Comment: Is the only difference in the code that you don't have a `Register` method for administrators? If so, can't you just have one `AccountService` and two interfaces?

Comment: @John The administrator AccountService should would include the following functionality: login, isUserSignedIn and Logout. As for the Customer's AccountService it would include more functionality such as password-reset ec.
I can't implement both interfaces in one AccountService since these apps are hosted seperately,

Comment: I see. You could derive them from a common base class in a library which provides the shared functionality, or you could compose them from other services (as you say) that provide that functionality.

Comment: @John thank you for the confirmation. I will try that implementation.

Comment: Admins can not reset their password?

Comment: Is this not a problem of authorization after you've determined the type of user you have? Going to great efforts to split code up, repeat it etc, it's only achieving the same thing as having one class, and some methods are decorated with EveryoneAuthAttribute and others decorated with CustomerOnlyAuthAttribute - once you know a person is admin they will never be able to call the customer only code, no?

Comment: this can be solved by Interface Segregation. Divide your interfaces into as small pieces as possible. Also I don't think services should depend on data (customer or admin) as long as the code logic is not changed. Using which apis is determined by your higher level of the app, such as the endpoint level or even the UI. Think about endpoints as resources, you can apply authorization to control which can be accessed by whom (as well as with other related data for authorizing).

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I agree, but since the two apps are separate and there will be one role per application, wouldn't it be a waste of resources to check for user authorization at a service level knowing that each app that's hosted separately will be having fixed roles?

Comment: @KingKing I did build the initial version of the project with an Identity Server implementation for authentication & role-based authorization, alongside a Web API to expose the business logic to the two presentation layers. But realized it's a lot simpler and secure to simply separate the two applications without leaving any attack vector that could be brute-forced.

Comment: But two applications just seems like security by obscurity to me - end of the day it’s up to you how you build your app, but in simplistic terms if I was building n account page for customers and for admins and admins couldn’t reset their password, it would be the same page with a bool somewhere that controlled the visibility of the reset journey and an authorization process on the back end that prohibited admins from using the reset process (to prevent brute forcing/provide multilayer security)